# What binding is the wcf service using when created from Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0

I was happily working on my services and client, everything working fine, when I decided to setup the security of it, and I got surprised that there is no binding information on the .config file. No protocol, No encoding...

How do I find out the binding it is using? it is definitely http since I was able to host on IIS ( no WAS I guess.. )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You will get the default values for security based on the default binding - if you want values other than the default, you'll have to declare a binding (either programatically or in the config file).  If you do this without setting a `name` attribute value, it will override the default settings and use your settings for all services that use that binding in that application.  .NET 4.0 greatly simplified the configuration requirements for WCF compared to 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default is `BasicHttpBinding` and `NetTcpBinding`.
See here: [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4 (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

Comment: To be more accurate, the default binding for http addresses is `BasicHttpBinding`, and for net.tcp addresses it is `NetTcpBinding`.  In other words, the default bindings are based on the protocol of the service.